# More complex view matrix calculation required to composite 3d models with 2d video

Tags: math, 3d, xna, 2d, tracking

I'm utilising some 2d / 3d tracking data (provided by [pfHoe](http://www.pfhoe.com/)) to help integrate some 3d models into the playback of some 2d video.

Things are working.... okay... but there's still some visible 'slipping' of the models against the video background and I suspect this is may be because the XNA CreatePerspective helper method isn't taking into account some of the additional data supplied by pfHoe such as independent horizontal / vertical field of view angles and focal length.

Would anyone be able to point me towards some examples of constructing view matrices that include such details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MSDN article shows you how to write a method which creates a perspective matrix that takes into account horizontal and vertical FOV independently (albeit, in C++)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147302%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
D3DXMATRIX 
ProjectionMatrix(const float near_plane, // Distance to near clipping 
                                         // plane
                 const float far_plane,  // Distance to far clipping 
                                         // plane
                 const float fov_horiz,  // Horizontal field of view 
                                         // angle, in radians
                 const float fov_vert)   // Vertical field of view 
                                         // angle, in radians
{
    float    h, w, Q;

    w = (float)1/tan(fov_horiz*0.5);  // 1/tan(x) == cot(x)
    h = (float)1/tan(fov_vert*0.5);   // 1/tan(x) == cot(x)
    Q = far_plane/(far_plane - near_plane);

    D3DXMATRIX ret;
    ZeroMemory(&ret, sizeof(ret));

    ret(0, 0) = w;
    ret(1, 1) = h;
    ret(2, 2) = Q;
    ret(3, 2) = -Q*near_plane;
    ret(2, 3) = 1;
    return ret;
}   // End of ProjectionMatrix
```

The math is further explained in the article linked above to aid you in writing a C# version of this method.  Good luck :-)

Comment: Hmmm... I may have to a little more as my first interpretation of it in C# gives some... odd... results... :)

private Matrix CreateProjection(float horizontalFov, float verticalFov, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
        {
            var w = 1f / (float)Math.Tan(horizontalFov * 0.5f);
            var h = 1f / (float)Math.Tan(verticalFov * 0.5f);
            var q = farPlane / (farPlane - nearPlane);
        
            return new Matrix(w, 0, 0, 0, 0, h, 0, 0, 0, 0, q, 1, 0, 0, -q * nearPlane, 0);
        }